# PythonAnywhere - Flask - 500 Internal whenever POST

Tags: python, flask, pythonanywhere

I have deployed my Flask app through PythonAnywhere, it displays, but for my index I've a login page, I try to login in and after I press Log In, it loads for 5 seconds then it gives me the 500 Internal Server error - Note: everything works fine on localhost.

Error log:

```
2017-01-20 08:31:39,216 :/home/stanciu/.virtualenvs/oldstyle/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py:145: UserWarning: MongoClient opened before fork. Create MongoClient with connect=False, or create client after forking. See PyMongo's documentation for details: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/faq.html#pymongo-fork-safe>
2017-01-20 08:31:39,216 :  "MongoClient opened before fork. Create MongoClient "
2017-01-20 08:32:09,239 :[2017-01-20 08:32:09,233] ERROR in app: Exception on / [POST]
2017-01-20 08:32:09,239 :Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-01-20 08:32:09,240 :  File "/home/stanciu/.virtualenvs/oldstyle/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
2017-01-20 08:32:09,240 :    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2017-01-20 08:32:09,240 :  File "/home/stanciu/.virtualenvs/oldstyle/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
2017-01-20 08:32:09,240 :    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2017-01-20 08:32:09,240 :  File "/home/stanciu/.virtualenvs/oldstyle/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
2017-01-20 08:32:09,240 :    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2017-01-20 08:32:09,240 :  File "/home/stanciu/.virtualenvs/oldstyle/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
2017-01-20 08:32:09,240 :    rv = self.dispatch_request()
2017-01-20 08:32:09,240 :  File "/home/stanciu/.virtualenvs/oldstyle/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
2017-01-20 08:32:09,240 :    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2017-01-20 08:32:09,240 :  File "/home/stanciu/oldstyle/untitled.py", line 23, in index
2017-01-20 08:32:09,240 :    login_user = users.find_one({'name' : request.form['username']})
2017-01-20 08:32:09,240 :  File "/home/stanciu/.virtualenvs/oldstyle/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 1102, in find_one
2017-01-20 08:32:09,240 :    for result in cursor.limit(-1):
2017-01-20 08:32:09,241 :  File "/home/stanciu/.virtualenvs/oldstyle/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1114, in next
2017-01-20 08:32:09,241 :    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
2017-01-20 08:32:09,241 :  File "/home/stanciu/.virtualenvs/oldstyle/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1036, in _refresh
2017-01-20 08:32:09,241 :    self.__collation))
2017-01-20 08:32:09,241 :  File "/home/stanciu/.virtualenvs/oldstyle/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 873, in __send_message
2017-01-20 08:32:09,241 :    **kwargs)
2017-01-20 08:32:09,241 :  File "/home/stanciu/.virtualenvs/oldstyle/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 888, in _send_message_with_response
2017-01-20 08:32:09,241 :    server = topology.select_server(selector)
2017-01-20 08:32:09,241 :  File "/home/stanciu/.virtualenvs/oldstyle/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 214, in select_server
2017-01-20 08:32:09,241 :    address))
2017-01-20 08:32:09,241 :  File "/home/stanciu/.virtualenvs/oldstyle/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 189, in select_servers
2017-01-20 08:32:09,241 :    self._error_message(selector))
2017-01-20 08:32:09,241 :ServerSelectionTimeoutError: No servers found yet
```

Comment: Is it a free account or?

Comment: It is. I want to test the platform before I buy a plan.

Comment: I had same problem. When using a free account and trying to get data from a remote mongodb server it happens. The problem is mongodb server send too late and it falls I guess.

Comment: There's no fix? Or it'll work whenever I switch from my free account to a premium one?

Comment: I am not sure but I can suggest you to change your database to sqlite its file based so you can create your app with it.

Comment: If your mongo instance is available on the internet, then upgrading will allow you to connect to it. If it's not available on the internet or doesn't actually exist, then you'll either need to create it or use different database.